# Android forwards compatibility

Tags: android, compatibility, forward

I just published my first application to the market, but i just found out that android.telephony.gsm.smsmanager was depreciated as of Android 1.6. My application depends on sending SMS messages, so it cannot not work in 1.6 or newer.

I built the project against 1.5, but I only have a device with 1.5 to test on. Since I built on 1.5, am I fine in terms of newer OSes, or will users get force closes?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Is there a way to send/receive SMS messages in the emulator? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually deprecated methods work just fine in subsequent API versions. (It's just a flag that roughly says that there is an updated and better way of doing that task.)

When it comes to sending and receiving SMSes in the emulator, have a look at the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#calling

Or other forums:

http://www.anddev.org/how_to_send_sms-t552.html

http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/sms-emulation-on-android.html

Comment: Yup, works fine. I can send SMS messages to and from emulators running 1.6-2.1. Thanks!